# Notification Center?

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios5

I have an app on appstore that uses notifications.

Today I got a support message from a customer having problems..

I already noticed that sometimes when upgrading from iOS 4.x -> 5.x notification center didn't automatically allow the app to send notifications..

However in this case the user does not even see the app in the notification center list.. I cannot reproduce this problem but is there anyone who knows how to fix this or knows the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after sending him some test cases it turned out that the app had to send a notifcation for it to appear in the list.. Wierd but the app now appears and works for the user..